# Salesforce DX connected app

Tags: salesforcedx, connected-apps, permission-sets, jwt

I am trying to build a connected app- connected to our prod environment so that our developers could spin up scratch orgs and work there, however I dont want them to be able to use org:login and change anything. So far the ive tried:

1. created a permission set for creating and editing ors and have assigned it to a read only user used to login to the connected app but i cant spin scratch orgs.
2. Ive tried limiting the connected apps permissions but i can still use org:login and see into the org.

any suggestion or recommendation is welcomed

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your developers with a [Permission Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm#!) entitling them to utilize Salesforce DX without providing them with System Administrator access to Production (the Dev Hub). A Connected App is not required in this case.

The required permissions are

> To give full access to the Dev Hub org, the permission set must contain these permissions.
>
> Object Settings > Scratch Org Info > Read, Create, and Delete
> Object Settings > Active Scratch Org > Read and Delete
> Object Settings > Namespace Registry > Read

You're not required to provide access to other core objects (such as Account) and are free to assign developers a profile that does not include these objects, so that they're unable to view data in the org.

For a continuous integration workflow, you'll want to use a Connected App with the JWT flow, but your developers won't use this flow directly - it'll be configured only via the CI solution itself.